# How does the OOM killer decide which process to kill first?

Tags: linux, memory, out-of-memory

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136294/47538) answer explains the actions taken by the kernel when an OOM situation is encountered based on the value of `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory`.

When `overcommit_memory` is set to 0 or 1, `overcommit` is enabled, and programs are allowed to allocate more memory than is really available.

Now what happens when we run out of memory in this situation? How does the *OOM killer* decide which process to kill first?

Comment: I believes that the values are 1 an 2 - not 0 and 1.

Comment: From here http://serverfault.com/questions/606185/how-does-vm-overcommit-memory-work , 0 and 1 are the correct values.

Comment: There is an excellent description available at https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer

Comment: According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting 0, 1, and 2 are all valid values.

Comment: another interesting link https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-oom-killer.html

Answer (score 172, accepted):

If memory is exhaustively used up by processes, to the extent which can possibly threaten the stability of the system, then the OOM killer comes into the picture.

**NOTE:** It is the task of the OOM Killer to continue killing processes until enough memory is freed for the smooth functioning of the rest of the process that the Kernel is attempting to run.

The OOM Killer has to select the **best** process(es) to kill. **Best** here refers to that process which will free up the maximum memory upon killing and is also the least important to the system.

The primary goal is to kill the least number of processes that minimizes the damage done and at the same time maximizing the amount of memory freed.

To facilitate this, the kernel maintains an `oom_score` for each of the processes. You can see the `oom_score` of each of the processes in the `/proc` filesystem under the `pid` directory.

```
$ cat /proc/10292/oom_score
```

The higher the value of `oom_score` of any process, the higher is its likelihood of getting killed by the *OOM Killer* in an out-of-memory situation.

#### How is the `OOM_Score` calculated?

> In David's patch set, the old badness() heuristics are almost entirely
> gone. Instead, the calculation turns into a simple question of what
> percentage of the available memory is being used by the process. If
> the system as a whole is short of memory, then "available memory" is
> the sum of all RAM and swap space available to the system.
>
> If instead, the OOM situation is caused by exhausting the memory allowed
> to a given cpuset/control group, then "available memory" is the total
> amount allocated to that control group. A similar calculation is made
> if limits imposed by a memory policy have been exceeded. In each case,
> the memory use of the process is deemed to be the sum of its resident
> set (the number of RAM pages it is using) and its swap usage.
>
> This calculation produces a percent-times-ten number as a result; a
> process which is using every byte of the memory available to it will
> have a score of 1000, while a process using no memory at all will get
> a score of zero. There are very few heuristic tweaks to this score,
> but the code does still subtract a small amount (30) from the score of
> root-owned processes on the notion that they are slightly more
> valuable than user-owned processes.
>
> One other tweak which is applied is to add the value stored in each
> process's oom_score_adj variable, which can be adjusted via /proc.
> This knob allows the adjustment of each process's attractiveness to
> the OOM killer in user space; setting it to -1000 will disable OOM
> kills entirely, while setting to +1000 is the equivalent of painting a
> large target on the associated process.

**References**

http://www.queryhome.com/15491/whats-happening-kernel-starting-killer-choose-which-process
https://serverfault.com/a/571326

Comment: Doesn't niceness also play a role?

Comment: There's also a useful `oom_score_adj`

Comment: Does niceness play a role?

Comment: niceness used to play a role but that changed. @Ramesh briefly glossed over this in the first paragraph about how `OOM_Score` is calculated but the crux is that now the oom score is only affected by three things:
1. how much memory is hypothetically available to a process (either through cgroup limits or system limits)
2. what percentage of that limit is the process currently using
3. the process' `oom_score_adj`