# How may I calculate the size of shared memory available to the system

Tags: memory, shared-memory

According to the [RHEL document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Shared_Memory-Setting_SHMALL_Parameter.html), the total amount of shared memory available on the system equals `shmall*PAGE_SIZE`.

After I completed the installation of RHEL 6, the value of the `shmall` kernel parameter defaults to 4294967296， which means that the total amount of shared memory pages that can be used system-wide is 4294967296, and the page size is 4096 B. So, based on the formula, the size of shared memory is

```
4294967296*4096/1024/1024/1024/1024 = 16 TB
```

... which is much more than the size of RAM (8 GB) the operating system has. How can an OS find 16 TB of shared memory to allocate?

So, is the size of `/dev/shm` equal to the size of shared memory? If not, how can I get the actual size of the shared memory?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. I have removed the second one, you can ask it as a separate question. Also, please [edit] your question and i) clarify why you say the system has less memory than what you show. What kind of memory are you referring to? How do you measure it? ii) How do you get 16TB from your formula? What you show is 16 gigabits, not 16 terabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct. shmall can be set higher than the available virtual memory. If you would try to use all of it then it would not fail because of shmall is exceeded but because of other reasons.

BTW there are also commands to find these IPC limits:

```
ipcs -l
lsipc  # util-linux>=2.27
```

Note that even the virtual memory is unlimited on Linux by default, greater-than RAM+swap. See

https://serverfault.com/questions/606185/how-does-vm-overcommit-memory-work

[How the OOM killer decides which process to kill first?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-the-oom-killer-decides-which-process-to-kill-first)

On the other hand you could *limit* the virtual memory per process using `ulimt -v` which wouldn't affect kernel's `/proc/sys/kernel/shmall` neither.

Comment: the result of ipcs -l is depend on the setting shmall,it does not show the real limits

Comment: @user4535727 Probably a bug because of integer overflow. Maybe it's correct for smaller values `echo $(( 1024*1024*1024 )) > /proc/sys/kernel/shmall;  ipcs -l`