# How can the OOM killer kill ulimit(ed) process?

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, memory-leaks

I'm playing with MongoDB clusters. After few OOM killers, I decided to ulimit mongoDB with memory to 4G of RAM.
After few hours, it was killed again with OOM.
So my question is not about MongoDB, it's about memory management in linux.
Here is an HTOP just a few minutes before OOM.
[image]

Why are there 4.2T of VIRT and only 11M of RES?

Some useful info:

```
root@mongodb: pmap -d 24059
....
mapped: 4493752480K    writeable/private: 2247504740K    shared: 2246203932K
```

Here is the dmesg log:

```
[617568.768581] bash invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x26000c0, order=2, oom_score_adj=0
[617568.768585] bash cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[617568.768590] CPU: 0 PID: 4686 Comm: bash Not tainted 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu
[617568.768591] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 02/16/2017
[617568.768592]  0000000000000286 00000000c18427a2 ffff8800a41f7b10 ffffffff813f9513
[617568.768595]  ffff8800a41f7cc8 ffff8800ba798000 ffff8800a41f7b80 ffffffff8120b53e
[617568.768597]  ffffffff81cd6fd7 0000000000000000 ffffffff81e677e0 0000000000000206
[617568.768600] Call Trace:
[617568.768605]  [<ffffffff813f9513>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[617568.768609]  [<ffffffff8120b53e>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
[617568.768613]  [<ffffffff81192ae2>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
[617568.768614]  [<ffffffff81192f09>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
[617568.768617]  [<ffffffff81198ef8>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x938/0xad0
[617568.768620]  [<ffffffff81199316>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x286/0x2a0
[617568.768622]  [<ffffffff811993cb>] alloc_kmem_pages_node+0x4b/0xc0
[617568.768625]  [<ffffffff8107eafe>] copy_process+0x1be/0x1b20
[617568.768627]  [<ffffffff811c1e44>] ? handle_mm_fault+0xcf4/0x1820
[617568.768631]  [<ffffffff81349133>] ? security_file_alloc+0x33/0x50
[617568.768633]  [<ffffffff810805f0>] _do_fork+0x80/0x360
[617568.768635]  [<ffffffff81080979>] SyS_clone+0x19/0x20
[617568.768639]  [<ffffffff81840b72>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[617568.768641] Mem-Info:
[617568.768644] active_anon:130 inactive_anon:192 isolated_anon:0
                 active_file:197 inactive_file:202 isolated_file:20
                 unevictable:915 dirty:0 writeback:185 unstable:0
                 slab_reclaimable:27072 slab_unreclaimable:5594
                 mapped:680 shmem:19 pagetables:1974772 bounce:0
                 free:18777 free_pcp:1 free_cma:0
[617568.768646] Node 0 DMA free:15904kB min:20kB low:24kB high:28kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[617568.768651] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3745 7966 7966 7966
[617568.768654] Node 0 DMA32 free:49940kB min:5332kB low:6664kB high:7996kB active_anon:512kB inactive_anon:756kB active_file:776kB inactive_file:800kB unevictable:2828kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):80kB present:3915776kB managed:3835092kB mlocked:2828kB dirty:0kB writeback:740kB mapped:2360kB shmem:52kB slab_reclaimable:69736kB slab_unreclaimable:8316kB kernel_stack:2272kB pagetables:3674424kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:4kB local_pcp:4kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:6592 all_unreclaimable? no
[617568.768658] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 4221 4221 4221
[617568.768660] Node 0 Normal free:9264kB min:6008kB low:7508kB high:9012kB active_anon:8kB inactive_anon:12kB active_file:12kB inactive_file:8kB unevictable:832kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:4587520kB managed:4322680kB mlocked:832kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:360kB shmem:24kB slab_reclaimable:38552kB slab_unreclaimable:14060kB kernel_stack:1680kB pagetables:4224664kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:14432 all_unreclaimable? yes
[617568.768664] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[617568.768667] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15904kB
[617568.768675] Node 0 DMA32: 11687*4kB (UME) 410*8kB (UME) 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 50028kB
[617568.768682] Node 0 Normal: 1878*4kB (UME) 1*8kB (H) 1*16kB (H) 0*32kB 1*64kB (H) 1*128kB (H) 2*256kB (H) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (H) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 9264kB
[617568.768691] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[617568.768692] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[617568.768693] 1275 total pagecache pages
[617568.768694] 249 pages in swap cache
[617568.768695] Swap cache stats: add 30567734, delete 30567485, find 17605568/26043265
[617568.768696] Free swap  = 7757000kB
[617568.768697] Total swap = 8388604kB
[617568.768698] 2129821 pages RAM
[617568.768699] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[617568.768699] 86402 pages reserved
[617568.768700] 0 pages cma reserved
[617568.768701] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[617568.768702] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[617568.768706] [  402]     0   402    25742      324      18       3       73             0 lvmetad
[617568.768708] [  440]     0   440    10722      173      22       3      301         -1000 systemd-udevd
[617568.768710] [  836]     0   836     4030      274      11       3      218             0 dhclient
[617568.768711] [  989]     0   989     1306      400       8       3       58             0 iscsid
[617568.768713] [  990]     0   990     1431      880       8       3        0           -17 iscsid
[617568.768715] [  996]   104   996    64099      210      28       3      351             0 rsyslogd
[617568.768716] [ 1001]     0  1001   189977        0      33       4      839             0 lxcfs
[617568.768718] [ 1005]   107  1005    10746      298      25       3      164          -900 dbus-daemon
[617568.768720] [ 1031]     0  1031     1100      289       8       3       36             0 acpid
[617568.768721] [ 1033]     0  1033    16380      290      36       3      203         -1000 sshd
[617568.768723] [ 1035]     0  1035     7248      341      18       3      180             0 systemd-logind
[617568.768725] [ 1038]     0  1038    68680        0      36       3      251             0 accounts-daemon
[617568.768726] [ 1041]     0  1041     6511      376      17       3       57             0 atd
[617568.768728] [ 1046]     0  1046    35672        0      27       5     1960             0 snapd
[617568.768729] [ 1076]     0  1076     3344      202      11       3       45             0 mdadm
[617568.768731] [ 1082]     0  1082    69831        0      38       4      342             0 polkitd
[617568.768733] [ 1183]     0  1183     4868      357      14       3       73             0 irqbalance
[617568.768734] [ 1192]   113  1192    27508      399      24       3      159             0 ntpd
[617568.768735] [ 1217]     0  1217     3665      294      12       3       39             0 agetty
[617568.768737] [ 1224]     0  1224     3619      385      12       3       38             0 agetty
[617568.768739] [10996]  1000 10996    11312      414      25       3      206             0 systemd
[617568.768740] [10999]  1000 10999    15306        0      33       3      475             0 (sd-pam)
[617568.768742] [14125]     0 14125    23842      440      50       3      236             0 sshd
[617568.768743] [14156]  1000 14156    23842        0      48       3      247             0 sshd
[617568.768745] [14157]  1000 14157     5359      425      15       3      512             0 bash
[617568.768747] [16461]   998 16461    11312      415      26       3      216             0 systemd
[617568.768748] [16465]   998 16465    15306        0      33       3      483             0 (sd-pam)
[617568.768750] [16470]   998 16470     4249        0      13       3       39             0 nrsysmond
[617568.768751] [16471]   998 16471    63005      109      26       3      891             0 nrsysmond
[617568.768753] [17374]   999 17374   283698        0      90       4     6299             0 XXX0
[617568.768754] [22123]     0 22123     8819      305      20       3       72             0 systemd-journal
[617568.768756] [28957]     0 28957     6932      379      17       3       90             0 cron
[617568.768758] [24059]   114 24059 1123438119        0 1973782    4288   127131             0 mongod
[617568.768760] [ 4684]     0  4684    12856      433      29       3      117             0 sudo
[617568.768761] [ 4685]     0  4685    12751      387      30       3      105             0 su
[617568.768763] [ 4686]     0  4686     5336      312      15       3      493             0 bash
[617568.768765] [18016]   999 18016     1127      145       7       3       25             0 sh
[617568.768766] [18017]   999 18017     9516      212      20       4      611             0 XXX1
[617568.768767] [18020]   999 18020     1127      120       8       3       24             0 sh
[617568.768769] [18021]   999 18021     9355      299      20       3      415             0 check-disk-usag
[617568.768770] [18024]     0 18024    12235      353      27       3      123             0 cron
[617568.768772] [18025]  1000 18025     2819      345      10       3       63             0 XXX2
[617568.768773] Out of memory: Kill process 24059 (mongod) score 508 or sacrifice child
[617568.772529] Killed process 24059 (mongod) total-vm:4493752476kB, anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB
```

Can somebody shed some light on this matter?

Like, why the RAM is full when MongoDB is using only 11M RES mem?
Does VIRT also use RAM? If yes which virtual address space?
Why did OOM kill it? too much pagetables (cause you see swap is almost empty)

EDIT: 
This guy asked for sorted top:

> Run top, press f and then highlight %MEM and press s to set the sort order. Post the output.
>   @Raman Sailopal

This is, of course, another processID but still, it should be same.

Output:

```
pu(s):  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.3%st
Mem:   3840468k total,  3799364k used,    41104k free,    12220k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    70736k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  SWAP DATA COMMAND
16213 mongodb   20   0 3443g 176m 9408 S  0.7  4.7 211:22.66 3.4t 3.9g mongod
 7706 sensu     20   0  661m  23m  804 S  0.0  0.6  20:20.92 637m 588m sensu-client
27120 ubuntu    20   0  595m  13m 7240 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.06 581m 569m mongo
24964 ubuntu    20   0 25936 8464 1708 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.54  17m 6736 bash
13858 ubuntu    20   0 26064 7620  728 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.75  18m 6864 bash
```

Comment: Threads have separate heap, can you get the total usage for the `mongod` process? No need to segregate threads.

Comment: @heemayl: `pmap -d 24059` is `mongod` process that OOM killed. What exactly information would make the question more informative?

Comment: OOM killer takes decision based on a lot of factors e.g. number of spawned processes, number of threads, virtual memory, RSS, how long it running and so on...

Comment: I know... that is the question. What metrics are important in order to understand OOM in this case?

Comment: Run top, press f and then highlight %MEM and press s to set the sort order. Post the output.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-the-oom-killer-decides-which-process-to-kill-first

Comment: Could you please add the output of: `cat /proc/meminfo` and of: `free -h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combination of three facts causes your oom problem: **small page size**, **large VIRT**, **pagetables**. Your logs clearly show that almost all the RAM was used by pagetables, not by process memory (for example, not by RESident pages - these got  mostly pressed out to swap).

The bummer about x86_64/x86 pagetables is that when you have multiple processes mapping exactly the same region of shared memory, they keep **separate** pagetables. Hence if one process maps 1 TB (it's included in the VIRT) kernel will create say 1 GB of pagetables (not shown in `top` at all, as these are not counted as belonging to a process). But if one hundred processes map the same 1 TB area, they take up 100 GB of your RAM to redunantly store the same metadata!

The amount of VIRT of a single process could be simply caused by opening and mmaping a file (either named or "anonymous") although there could be a lot of alternative explanations.

I guess the oom killer doesn't take size of pagetables into account when killing a process. In your case apparently mongodb was the primary candidate for oom kill in terms of RES usage. Despite the memory gain would be miniscule, the system had no choice, so it killed what it could kill.

The most obvious way to avoid your problem would be to use **huge pages**, if only mongodb supported these (I'm not suggesting to use transparent huge pages, instead consider vanilla non-transparent huge pages). Cursory search says sadly mongodb doesn't support even non-transparent huge pages.

Another way is to limit the number of spawned processes or somehow decrease their VIRT size.