# Out of Memory Killer OOM and Swap

Tags: swap, out-of-memory

Greetings to the service of dear masters and masters
I have a question :
Thanks for pointing me to a process called Out of Memory Killer in Linux, or OOM for short, how it works and what the processes are for it, and what it has to do with swap. Thank you for your help.
Thank you

Comment: No research, no nothing. I see no reason for this question not to be closed.

Comment: @MohammadBayat you did not ask a question

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in full in various locations, try google search.

Here's just one

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html

Other similar questions, with comprehensive answers

- [Will Linux start killing my processes without asking me if memory gets short?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/will-linux-start-killing-my-processes-without-asking-me-if-memory-gets-short/136294#136294)